# Proving that $\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{i^2}<2-\frac1n$ for $n>1$ by induction

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, summation, induction, telescopic-series

> Prove by induction that
>   $1 + \frac {1}{4} + \frac {1}{9} + ... +\frac {1}{n^2} < 2 - \frac{1}{n}$ for all $n>1$

I got up to using the inductive hypothesis to prove that $P(n+1)$ is true but I couldn't figure out algebraically how to set simplify the right hand side from
$$2 - \left(\frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{(n+1)^2}\right)$$ to  $$ 2 -\frac{1}{n+1}$$

Comment: For $n$ greater than what? Clearly for $n=1$ the inequality does not hold.

Comment: edited, for $n > 1$

Comment: Should there be ellipsis? $$1 + \frac {1}{4} + \frac {1}{9} + \dotsb+ \frac {1}{n^2} < 2 - \frac{1}{n}$$

Comment: See also [Proving $ 1+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{9}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n^2}\leq 2-\frac{1}{n}$ for all $n\geq 2$ by induction](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1220203) and other questions [linked there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/1220203).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key in this problem is really an algebraic "trick" or manipulation to coax out the right-hand side from the left. You've presumably verified the base case (for $n=2$). You then assumed that $\color{blue}{\sum_{i=1}^k\frac{1}{i^2}=2-\frac{1}{k}}$ for some fixed $k\geq 2$. Now, your goal is to use this assumption (called the inductive hypothesis) to prove that $$\color{green}{\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}\frac{1}{i^2}=2-\frac{1}{k+1}}.$$
Starting with the left-hand side,
\begin{align}
\color{green}{\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}\frac{1}{i^2}} &= \color{blue}{\sum_{i=1}^k\frac{1}{i^2}}+\frac{1}{(k+1)^2}\tag{by defn. of $\Sigma$}\\[1em]
&< \color{blue}{\left(2-\frac{1}{k}\right)}+\frac{1}{(k+1)^2}\tag{by inductive hypothesis}\\[1em]
&= 2-\frac{1}{k+1}\left(\frac{k+1}{k}-\frac{1}{k+1}\right)\tag{manipulate}\\[1em]
&= 2-\frac{1}{k+1}\left(\frac{k^2+k+1}{k(k+1)}\right)\tag{simplify}\\[1em]
&< \color{green}{2-\frac{1}{k+1}}.\tag{$\dagger$}
\end{align}
we end up at the right-hand side, completing the inductive proof.

---

**$(\dagger)$:** How did I get from the "simplify" step to the $(\dagger)$ step? Well, the numerator is $k^2+k+1$ and the denominator is $k^2+k$. We note that, $k^2+k+1>k^2+k$ (this boils down to accepting that $1>0$). Since $\frac{1}{k+1}$ is being multiplied by something greater than $1$, this means that what is being subtracted from $2$ in the "simplify" step is *larger* than what is being subtracting from $2$ in the $(\dagger)$ step. Does that make sense? The main "trick" in the proof above is in the "manipulate" step, where you make a subtle connection with what the right-hand side of what you are trying to prove. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

It amounts to check that
$$-\frac1n+\frac1{(n+1)^2}<-\frac1{n+
1}\iff\frac1{(n+1)^2}<\frac1n-\frac1{n+
1}=\frac1{n(n+1)}—\iff n+1>n.$$