# Proving inequality for induction proof: $\frac1{(n+1)^2} + \frac1{n+1} < \frac1n$

Tags: inequality, summation, induction, telescopic-series

In an induction proof for $\sum_{k = 1}^n \frac{1}{k^2} \leq 2 - \frac{1}{n}$ (for $n \geq 1$), I was required to prove the inequality $\frac{1}{(n+1)^2} + \frac{1}{n+1} < \frac{1}{n}$.

This is my attempt:

$$ \begin{align} \frac{1}{(n+1)^2} + \frac{1}{n+1} &= \frac{1+(n+1)}{(n+1)^2} \\ 
                                                   &=\frac{n+2}{(n+1)^2} \\
                                                   &=\frac{n+2}{n^2 + 2n + 1} \\
                                                   &<\frac{n+2}{n^2 + 2n} (\text{since  } n \geq 1)\\
                                                   &=\frac{n+2}{n(n+2)}\\
                                                   &=\frac{1}{n} \end{align} $$

I am just wondering if there is a simpler way of doing this.

Comment: for $n=1$, the inequality $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k^2}<2-\frac{1}{n}$ is not true. it only holds for $n>2$.

Comment: I think the < should be $\geq$.

Comment: No, it's correct. Because as $n\rightarrow \infty$ the inequality approaches $\frac{\pi^2}{6}$.

Comment: Sorry should be $\leq$

Comment: Nice variety of solutions. I upvoted then all.

Comment: See also: [Proving $ 1+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{9}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n^2}\leq 2-\frac{1}{n}$ for all $n\geq 2$ by induction](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1220203) and other [posts linked there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/1220203).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of comparing $\frac{1}{(n+1)^2} + \frac{1}{n+1}$ and $\frac{1}{n}$, we can compare $\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}$ and $\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}$. Then, what we have is
$$\frac{1}{(n+1)^2} = \frac{1}{(n+1)(n+1)} < \frac{1}{n(n+1)}=\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1} \implies \frac{1}{(n+1)^2} < \frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}$$
$$\implies \frac{1}{(n+1)^2} + \frac{1}{n+1} < \frac{1}{n}$$

---

Alternatively, by using the same way, we could try to prove 
$$\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}-\frac{1}{(n+1)} > 0$$
For this one, we have
$$\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}-\frac{1}{(n+1)} = \frac{(n+1)^2-n-n(n+1)}{n(n+1)^2} = \frac{1}{n(n+1)^2} > 0$$
since $n \ge 1$. Therefore, the result follows.

Answer (score 15):

To prove the inequality you were required to prove, note

$\dfrac1{n+1}+\dfrac1{(n+1)^2}<\dfrac1{n+1}+\dfrac1{(n+1)^2}+\dfrac1{(n+1)^3}+...=\dfrac{\dfrac1{1+n}}{1-\dfrac1{n+1}}=\dfrac1n$

Answer (score 7):

Multiply through by $n(n+1)^2$ (a positive number since $n \ge 1$ ) to get $$n+n(n+1) < (n+1)^2$$
$$n < (n+1)^2 - n(n+1)$$
$$n < (n+1)(n+1-n)$$
$$n < n+1$$
Which is true of course for all $n$; in particular $n\ge 1$

Comment: I like this answer but I'm looking for something that is simpler / more obvious.

Comment: Another method is to use the common fraction of $n(n+1)^2$ and bring everything to one side: the result is similar: $n(n+1)^2 \gt 0$ which for the given conditions is true.

Answer (score 4):

Just for the fun of it, you can re-write your inequality as:
$$\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}>\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}.$$
This can be re-writen as:
$$\int_{n}^{n+1}\frac{1}{x^2}dx>\frac{1}{(n+1)^2},$$
or, if $f(x)=\dfrac{1}{x^2}$:
$$\int_{n}^{n+1}f(x)dx>f(n+1),$$
which is obvious if you consider that $f$ is strictly decreasing and positive on $(0,+\infty)$ and that the right-hand side of the inequality is the area of a rectangle with height $f(n+1)$ and a basis of $1$ - see the figure below.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your way is right, but you need to open the sumation from $k=2$: 
$$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k^2}=1+\sum_{k=2}^n\frac{1}{k^2}<1+\sum_{k=2}^n\frac{1}{k(k-1)}=1+\sum_{k=2}^n\left(\frac{1}{k-1}-\frac{1}{k}\right)=2-\frac{1}{n}.$$