# Lost on step of proof

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-explanation

Reading [this proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1220261/881209), I don't understand a part of the inductive step (copied below). I do not understand how we are going from

$$
\leq 2-\frac{1}{k}+\frac{1}{(k+1)^2}\quad\text{(by $S(k)$)}
$$
to
$$
= 2-\frac{1}{k+1}\left(\frac{k+1}{k}-\frac{1}{k+1}\right)
$$

**Inductive step:** Fix some $k\geq 2$ and suppose that $S(k)$ is true. It remains to show that
$$
S(k+1) : 1+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{9}+\cdots+\frac{1}{k^2}+\frac{1}{(k+1)^2}\leq 2-\frac{1}{k+1}
$$
holds. Starting with the left-hand side of $S(k+1)$,
\begin{align}
1+\frac{1}{4}+\cdots+\frac{1}{k^2}+\frac{1}{(k+1)^2}
&\leq 2-\frac{1}{k}+\frac{1}{(k+1)^2}\quad\text{(by $S(k)$)}\\[1em]
&= 2-\frac{1}{k+1}\left(\frac{k+1}{k}-\frac{1}{k+1}\right)\\[1em]
&= 2-\frac{1}{k+1}\left(\frac{k^2+k+1}{k(k+1)}\right)\tag{simplify}\\[1em]
&< 2-\frac{1}{k+1}.\tag{$\dagger$}
\end{align}

Comment: If you multiply out $-\frac{1}{k+1}\left(\frac{k+1}{k}-\frac{1}{k+1}\right)$ you will see that you get $-\frac{1}{k}+\frac{1}{(k+1)^2}$.

Comment: @rogerl thank you. How do you think they figured out how to expand it that way? Do I just need to read up more on manipulating fractions?

Comment: This proof obscures what is going on. It is hiding that, for $n>1$ $$\frac1{n^2}<\frac1{n(n-1)}=\frac1{n-1}-\frac1n$$ and then using the right side to get a “telescoping sum.” This is probably where the proof came from, originally.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Okay, that makes a ton of sense. Thank you.