# Proof verification for proving $\forall n \ge 2, 1 + \frac1{2^2} + \frac1{3^2} + \cdots + \frac1{n^2} < 2 − \frac1n$ by induction

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, summation, induction, solution-verification

> Prove by mathematical induction: $\forall n \ge 2, 1 + \frac1{2^2} + \frac1{3^2} + \cdots + \frac1{n^2} < 2 − \frac1n$

Basis Step: (We want to show, $P(2)$, which is 1 + $\frac1{2^2}<2-\frac12$).

$\frac1{2^2}=\frac14$, and $2-\frac12=\frac32$

So, $\frac1{2^2}<2-\frac12$.

Inductive step: (We want to show, $\forall n\ge2,\mathrm P(n)\to\mathrm P(n+1)$.

Let $k\ge2$ be an integer, arbitrary & fixed.

(We want to show, $\mathrm P(k)\to\mathrm P(k+1)$).

(I.H.) Assume $1+\frac1{2^2}+\frac1{3^2}+\cdots+\frac1{k^2}<2-\frac1k$ ("$\mathrm P(k)$")

(We want to show $\mathrm P(k+1)$, which is $1+\frac1{2^2}+\frac1{3^2}+\cdots+\frac1{(k+1)^2}<2−\frac1{k+1}$)

$$\begin{align}
1+\frac1{2^2}+\frac1{3^2}+\cdots+\frac1{(k+1)^2}&<2−\frac1{k+1}+\frac1{(k+1)^2}\tag{by I.H.}\\
&=2-\frac1k+\frac1{k^2+2k+1}
\end{align}$$

(Thus, $\mathrm P(k)\to\mathrm P(k+1)$ for all $\mathrm k\ge2$
 Also, $\mathrm P(2)$, so by mathematical induction, $\forall k\ge2,\mathrm P(k)$)

Can someone look at my solution and see if it is correct? I'm not 100% confident with it.

Comment: That's not a solution.

Comment: Basis step is $1+\frac{1}{2^2}<2-\frac{1}{2}$, not $\frac{1}{2^2}<2-\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: The ideas are all there, but you still need to show that $\frac{1}{k} - \frac{1}{k^2 + 2k +1} \geq \frac{1}{k+1}$.

Comment: Bad formatted, **and** a duplicate.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio The formatting is exactly the way my professor showed us and this is a duplicate of what?

Comment: @PedroM. I thought it is shown but if not, I'm unsure how to proceed.

Comment: Well I'm afraid don't see where you prove the inequality. If you think you've shown it, in which line (of your solution) is this proven?

Comment: @PedroM. The line that has (by I.H.) at the end just above where it says (Thus, P(k)→P(k+1) for all k≥2 is where I think it's proven.

Comment: [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1251544/sum-k-1n-frac1k2-2-frac1n) is an *exact* duplicate

Comment: Or [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1220203/proving-1-frac14-frac19-cdots-frac1n2-leq-2-frac1n-for). Pretty easy to find duplicates of this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK. It appears you are not interested in looking at other questions that pose the same question; rather, you solely want to know whether or not your own solution is correct. To this, I would say **no**. If I were your teacher, then I would probably give you 6/10 on this problem. Why?

Using the induction hypothesis, you should have
$$
\color{blue}{1+\frac{1}{4}+\cdots+\frac{1}{k^2}}+\frac{1}{(k+1)^2}< \color{blue}{2-\frac{1}{k}}+\frac{1}{(k+1)^2}\tag{1}
$$
and not
$$
1+\frac1{2^2}+\frac1{3^2}+\cdots+\frac1{(k+1)^2}<2−\frac1{k+1}+\frac1{(k+1)^2},\tag{2}
$$
as it currently stands. The induction hypothesis is used on the part highlighted in blue in $(1)$, but you did not use it properly in $(2)$. Finally, by your own admission, your goal is to end up with
$$
1+\frac1{2^2}+\frac1{3^2}+\cdots+\frac1{(k+1)^2}<2−\frac1{k+1},
$$
but all you did was write
$$
1+\frac1{2^2}+\frac1{3^2}+\cdots+\frac1{(k+1)^2}=2-\frac1k+\frac1{k^2+2k+1},
$$
and then you claimed you proved the result (something you obviously did not do). In $(1)$, your task is to reduce the right-hand side down into $2-\frac{1}{k+1}$, thus proving $P(k+1)$. You can do this like so:
\begin{align}
1+\frac{1}{4}+\cdots+\frac{1}{k^2}+\frac{1}{(k+1)^2}
&<2-\frac{1}{k}+\frac{1}{(k+1)^2}\quad\text{(by $P(k)$, the ind. hyp.)}\\[1em]
&= 2-\frac{1}{k+1}\left(\frac{k+1}{k}-\frac{1}{k+1}\right)\\[1em]
&= 2-\frac{1}{k+1}\left(\frac{k^2-k}{k(k+1)}\right)\\[1em]
&\leq 2-\frac{1}{k+1}.\qquad\text{(since $k\geq 1, k^2-k\geq 0$)}
\end{align}
Why could you never reach this end form? It's because you did not apply the induction hypothesis properly in $(2)$.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not looking for induction you can follow this path

$$0\le \frac{1}{k^2}\le \frac{1}{k(k-1)}$$

And after noting that $\frac{1}{k(k-1)}=\frac{1}{k-1}-\frac{1}{k}$ and the sum telescopes...

Comment: This is correct, but not an answer to the question asked by the OP. If all that mattered were a solution to the problem, then, as JackDaurizio stated, this is a duplicate.

Comment: You're right @Pedro M. But one could have noted also that $\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}\lt \frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}$ is the key to an inductive proof

Answer (score 0):

For the proof step, notice that $2-\frac{1}{k} <2 -\frac{1}{k+1}$, and after subtracting $\frac{1}{(k+1)^2}$, and then show that $2- \frac{1}{k}<2 - \frac{1}{k+1}(1+\frac{1}{k+1})$