# A Question regarding mathematical induction.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, induction

The principle of mathematical induction (as I understand stand it) states the following -

---

Consider a property $P(n)$ defined for the positive integers $n \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$. Suppose the following two statements are true

1. $P(1)$ is true.
2. For all $k \geq 1$, if $P(k)$ is true then $P(k+1)$ is also true.

Since $P(1)$ is true, and $\forall k \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$ $P(k+1)$ is true whenever $P(k)$ is true, $P(n)$ is true for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$.

---

### I understand everything except the point "If $P(k)$ is true for all $k \geq 1, k \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$". How can we make such an assumption? I could have also assumed that $P(k)$ is true for all $k \geq 2, k \in \mathbb{Z}$. On what grounds are these assumptions valid? It seems to me that you pick any integer for which $P(k)$ is true. I understand that assuming $P(k)$ is valid for $k \geq 1$ allows us to use the base case and conclude that $P(n)$ is true for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, but what I cannot understand is why this is a valid assumption.

This post isn't the same as this one [Mathematical induction question: why can we "assume $P(k)$ holds"?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/106404/mathematical-induction-question-why-can-we-assume-pk-holds). That post asks "how can we assume $P(k)$ holds and then show that $P(k+1)$ follows without ever proving the truth of P(k)$. My question is different. It asks why $P(k), k \geq 1$ is assumed to be true and not $P(k)$ for some other positive integer other than $1$.

Comment: It is an [axiom of arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms): if property $P$ holds of $1$ (the first number) and if it holds for a number $k$ whatever then it holds for its successor $k+1$, then property $P$ holds for **every** number $n$.

Comment: "On what grounds are these assumptions valid? " They are not valid. We can just "assume" them, and we do. Take an example, namely that $1+3+5+\cdots (2n+1)=(n+1)^2$, and use this induction principle. $P(1)$ says that $1+3=2^2$, which is true. Now assume that $P(k)$ is true for $k=1,2,\ldots ,n$. This is not "valid", we just assume it. But then we can prove $P(n+1)$ from it. Now this we apply to $P(1)$.

Comment: The intuition is simple: $P$ holds of $1$; then, by second part: $P(1) \to P(1+1)$, it holds for $2$. Now repeat...

Comment: You've mis-stated $2$. It should be, "for all $k\ge1$, if $P(k)$ then $P(k+1)$".

Comment: You're being asked to prove an if-then statement. Suppose you were asked to prove "If an animal is a dog, then it has four legs." Would you ask "why am I allowed to assume the animal is a dog?"?

Answer (score 1):

You can *assume* anything you want!  And that assumption, by itself, doesn't mean anything, so none of this should trouble you.

However, the fact that we can infer something (call it 'bla bla') *from* an assumption does mean something: it means that the conditional statement "*if* [assumption], then [bla bla] " is true.

With induction, the inductive step shows that for any $k$: *if* $P(k)$, then $P(k+1)$. To show that, you typically pick some arbitrary $k$, assume $P(k)$, and try to show $P(k+1)$.  That may look as if it is assuming that $P(k)$ is true for any $k$, but it isn't.

Compare:  Suppose I ask you to prove that any number divisible by $4$ is an even number. To do this, I assume you would start with: "OK, let's assume that $n$ is some arbitrary number divisible by $4$".  But note: that is totally not the same as assuming that any arbitrary number is divisible by $4$. Likewise, when in the inductive step you assume that $k$ is some arbitrary umber for which $P(k)$ is true, you are not assuming that $P(k)$ is true for any number $k$.

Also note that the inductive step by itself also does not mean that $P(k)$ is true for any $k$.  What the inductive step *does* mean is that *if* $P(1)$, then $P(2)$. And it also means that *if* $P(2)$, then $P(3)$. And that *if* $P(3)$, then $P(4)$. Etc.    ... which does not mean $P(k)$ for any $k$.

But now throw in the base case $P(1)$, and suddenly you now *can* conclude $P(2)$, ... and therefore $P(3)$, ... and therefore $P(4)$, etc. ... meaning that between the inductive base *and* the inductive step, you obtain that $P(k)$ for any $k$.

Answer (score 0):

> I understand everything except the point "If $P(k)$ is true for all
> $k \geq 1, k \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$". How can we make such an assumption? I
> could have also assumed that $P(k)$ is true for all $k \geq 2, k \in
> > \mathbb{Z}$. On what grounds are these assumptions valid?

Hint: If you want to prove that $A$ implies $B$, you can start by first assuming that $A$ is true and then prove that $B$ must also be true. Then you can conclude that $A$ implies $B$.

(Maybe proofs in propositional and predicate logic should be taught *before* proofs by induction.)