# Favourite proofs by induction?

Tags: soft-question, induction, big-list

I am searching for nice proofs by induction, that can be used to teach. I remember this example, that my analysis professor presented to us in first semester and I am searching for more such easily understood examples.

**Theorem**: A chess-board with side length $2^n$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$, where one square in the corner is cut off (see picture for $n=2$), can be tessellated by pieces consisting of 3 squares in an L-shape (see picture).

[image: The piece to tessellate the board]

[image: Board for $n=2$]

**Proof**: By induction. For $n=1$, the piece and the board have the same shape. For $n>1$, the board having side lengt $2^n$, divide it into 4 such boards with side length $2^{n-1}$, where one of those smaller boards has its cut-off corner in the corner of the bigger board and the other three have their cut-off corner in the center of the bigger board, leaving 3 pieces in the center, which can be filled by one more L-piece.

Comment: See http://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/220/good-simple-examples-of-induction and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/423513/how-to-teach-mathematical-induction

Comment: [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/294677/looking-for-induction-problems-that-are-not-formula-based) question might interest you.

Comment: I always liked the proof of $\frac{d}{dx} x^n = nx^{n-1}$ using induction. It's easy and prettier (to my taste) than using Newton's Binomium.

Comment: I like the proof of the Fibonacci matrix identity. Very simple but nice.