# Is $\pi$ approximately algebraic?

Tags: pi

As we know, $\pi$ is transcendental, meaning that there is no rational numbers $a_0,\ldots,a_n\in\mathbb{Q}$ such that
$$a_0+a_1\pi+\cdots+a_n\pi^n=0.$$
But I was wondering if we can get this as a limiting process: Is there a sequence of polynomials $\{p_n(x)\}_{n=1}^\infty$ with rational coefficients such that the first positive root of $p_n(x)$ tends to $\pi$ as $n\to\infty$?

Comment: Sure, $p_1(x)=x-3$, $p_2(x)=x-3.1$, $p_3(x)=x-3.14$, and so on.

Comment: I think this has almost nothing to do with "algebraic number", because it involves a limit. So perhaps the title is not so good.

Comment: Vadim's comment above is exactly to the point.  $\pi$ is not merely "approximately algebraic" in this sense; it is approximately *rational*.  You can fix $n=1$ and find any number of sequences of first-degree polynomials with the desired property. To make the question interesting you need to include some measure of how well-approximated $\pi$ is by the roots of the polynomials. The [irrationality measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville_number#Irrationality_measure) is a measure of this type.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, 
$$\sin\pi=0$$
so the first positive root of
$$p_n(x)=x-\frac{1}{3!}x^3+\frac{1}{5!}x^5-\cdots+\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}x^{2n+1}$$
tends to $\pi$ as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: There is more involved here. Let $\{f_n:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R\}$ be a sequence of functions, and suppose that every function of the sequence has a least positive root, say $a_n$. Is it true that if $f_n\to f$ and $f$ has also a first positive root $a$, then $a_n$ converges and its limit is $a$? I don't find it trivial at all.