# Density of computable numbers

Tags: real-numbers

Proposition: for any real number, there exists a [computable number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computable_number) that is arbitrarily close to it.

Is this proposition true/false/undecided?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, because for every real number there is a *rational* number arbitrarily close to it, and every rational number is computable.