# calculate radius of circle that by given length of square that is inside it

Tags: geometry, circles

in this picture a length of square edge is 8 cm. I want to calculate the radius of circle. i try to calculate it, but i don't know how.

[image]

I calculate this:

[image]

Comment: Hint: The "subtriangles" in the red triangle are similar.

Comment: It is known that ratio of radius and side is $5/8$. Look at [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1188845/does-the-square-or-the-circle-have-the-greater-perimeter-a-surprisingly-hard-pr/1189457#1189457) answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let M be the center of the circle and let M' be the (orthogonal) projection of M 
on AB. Let r denote the radius of the circle. Then $r=|EM|=|AM'|, |AM'|+|M'B|=8, |MM'|^2+|M'B|^2=|MB|^2=r^2$. So we get $(8-r)^2+4^2=r^2$ which imlpies $r=5$

Answer (score 1):

Mark the center of circle as point $O$.

Mark the intersection of the red line and the square edge $BC$ as $F$.

Draw a line from $O$ to $B$ in your diagram. The length of this line must be equal to the radius of the circle, $r$.

The length of the line from $O$ to $F$ must then be equal to $8-r$ as $EO=r$ and $EF=8$.

Now use pythagorus in triangle $OBF$ to get:
$$r^2=4^2+(8-r)^2$$and solve for $r$

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the cathetus you labeled with 2*sqrt(10) actually has length $\sqrt{80}=2\sqrt{20}$. But you don't actually need this.

Let's call the third corner of the red triangle F. Let M be the intersection of EF and BC. Then $\angle MEB=\angle MBF$. Therefore, the triangles $\triangle MEB$ and $\triangle MBF$ are alike. So $MF$ has length 2, $EF$ has length 10 and the radius is 5.