# To find the side of a square whose two vertices lie on a circle

Tags: geometry

> Two vertices of a square lie on a circle of radius *r*,and two other vertices lie on a tangent to this circle. Then each side of a square is -
> $$(A)\frac{3r}{2}\quad
> (B)\frac{4r}{3}\quad
> (C)\frac{6r}{5}\quad
> (D)\frac{8r}{5}$$
> [Source](https://www.isical.ac.in/%7Eadmission/IsiAdmission/PreviousQuestion/BStat-BMath-UGA-2020.pdf)

After drawing the diagram I found that two vertices lie outside the circle and two on the circle ,but I can't tell whether the diagonal of the square passes through the center of the circle. I am stuck here.

Comment: If the diagonal(s) of the square passed through the center of the circle, then each side of the square would be $\sqrt2r$, which is not an option.

Comment: If you can use trigonometry solve $r+r\cos \alpha=2 r \sin \alpha$

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does the square or the circle have the greater perimeter? A surprisingly hard problem for high schoolers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1188845/does-the-square-or-the-circle-have-the-greater-perimeter-a-surprisingly-hard-pr)

Comment: (Essentially a duplicate, since the geometry in the linked problem is the same and the answer to this question is at the core of the answer to that one)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you draw a diameter for the circle from the point of tangency, it bisects the chord connecting the two points of the square that lie on the circle. The chord theorem says

$$\left(s\over2\right)^2=s(2r-s)$$

from which you can find that

$$s={8r\over5}$$

Comment: Nice, I just looked up this theorem, I am having a hard time without this theorem.

Comment: https://www.dummies.com/education/math/geometry/how-to-use-the-chord-chord-power-theorem/