# The square and circle below are tangent at one point and meet at four other points. Whats the radius?

Tags: geometry, circles, tangent-line

The square and circle below are tangent at one point and meet at four other points, as shown. If the side of the square is 8 units long, what's the radius of the circle?

[image]

Comment: I'm *pretty sure* this question already has an answer here somewhere. I'll see if I can find it.

Comment: Found it: ["Does the square or the circle have the greater perimeter? A surprisingly hard problem for high schoolers"](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1188845/409).

Comment: The answer is here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3022946/finding-all-possible-proofs

Comment: If Radius, breadth and height are resp $( R, 2b, 2h)$ We have $ \sqrt {b^2+h^2}=R,\, b+R= 2 h\,$ Eliminate R and solve quadratic equation $ \rightarrow \dfrac{b}{h}= \dfrac34,\, \dfrac{b}{R}= \dfrac35,\,$