# Hamiltonian path on a chessboard with prescribed endpoints

Tags: graph-theory, recreational-mathematics, hamiltonian-path

On an 8 x 8 chessboard consider two squares to be adjacent if and only if they share a common side.  All paths below will consist of steps which join one square to an adjacent one.  Under these conditions it is easy to construct a Hamiltonian cycle of the chessboard but quite another matter to find Hamiltonian paths with specified boundary conditions.  Suppose A and B are two squares of opposite colors.  A little bit of experimentation will (probably) convince  one that while it seems to be possible to find a Hamiltonian path
from A to B$\,$,$\,$ the amount of guesswork involved can be aggravating.
Is there any way to improve on trial and error?

Questions:

1) Is it always true that there is a Hamiltonian path joining A to B (as above)?

2) If so, can one give a systematic procedure to find it or at least cut the
 guesswork to a minimum?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried doing a construction by induction on board sizes that are powers of $2$?  Something extremely similar to http://math.stackexchange.com/a/461273/30402 should work, after a finite amount of legwork to handle different cases.