# induction proof of the fact that $n^2-9n+10$ is even

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, induction

I have following problem: I need to prove that $n^2-9n+10$ is even, by induction.
I started with $n^2-9n+10 = 2k $ for some integer $k$.
$n=1$:  $1-9+10 = 2$ which is even
for $n=k$ : $k^2-9k+10 = 2k $
for $n=k+1$: $(k+1)^2 - 9(k+1) +10 = 2(k+1) $
I do not know how to continue and would have liked to ask you if you could help me with this matter?
Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: expand your expression and use induction hypothesis

Comment: Expand $(k+1)^2 - 9(k+1) + 10$ to get $k^2 + 2k + 1 - 9k-9 = k^2 -9k + 10 - 18$, and use the induction hypothesis.

Comment: Read [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/172435/proof-by-induction-n2n-is-even), it helps how to do the induction.

Comment: Thank you, I will have a look at some more proofs. Thank you for your advices!

Comment: This can also be proven without induction, since for odd $n$: $n^2$ is odd as is $9\cdot n$, so their difference is even, and adding 10 keeps it even.

Similarly, for even $n$, $n^2$ and $9\cdot n$ are both even, so their difference is as well.

Comment: Simpler: in $n(n-9)$, one of the factors is even.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When $n=1$, $1^2-9 \cdot 1 +10 = 2$ is even. Now, suppose there is some $n$ for which $n^2-9 \cdot n + 10$ is even. That is, there is a $l \in \mathbb{Z}$ with $n^2-9 \cdot n + 10=2l$. We need to show that $(n+1)^2-9 \cdot (n+1) +10$ is again even. Note:
\begin{equation}
(n+1)^2-9 \cdot (n+1) +10=n^2+2n+1-9n-9+10\\
=(n^2-9n+10)+2n-8 \\
=2l+2(n-4) \\
=2(l+n-4).
\end{equation}

Comment: Wow, that was really fast. Thanks a lot I will do some more induction proofs to practise it more. This helps me a lot, thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

**Induction plus modular arithmetic**:

If
$$n^2-9n+10\equiv0\mod2,$$
then
$$(n+1)^2-9(n+1)+10\equiv(n^2-9n+10)+(2n+1-9)\equiv0\mod2.$$

Answer (score 0):

Remark:

The $k$ in your current setting are used to mean two different things, it would be great to use different notations.

Suppose $k^2-9k+10=2l$ for some integer $l$.

Show that $(k+1)^2-9(k+1)+10$ is even.

\begin{align}
(k+1)^2-9(k+1)+10&=k^2+2k+1-9k-9+10\\
&=(k^2-9k+10)+(2k+1-9)
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you for your quick response Siong Thye Goh!

Answer (score 0):

Just expand $(n+1)^2-9(n+1)+10$, group the terms so that you have $(n^2-9n+10)$ plus some function, and prove that that function is even.
$$(n+1)^2-9(n+1)+10=(n^2-9n+10)+2n+1+10-9$$
$$(n^2-9n+10)+2(n+1)$$