# Proof with induction that $n^2+n$ is even, when $n \in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: proof-verification, induction

## Problem

Proof with induction that $n^2+n$ is even when $n \in \mathbb{N}$

## Attempt to solve

$n^2+n$ is even when it satisfies:
$$ n^2+n \mod 2 = 0 $$
meaning it's divisible by 2. I can begin to proof that this statement holds when $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

### Base case

the statement holds when $n=0$

$$ 0^2+0 \mod 2 = 0 $$

Which is true since $0$ divided any $n\in \mathbb{N}$ is $0$.

### Inductive step

Assume statement holds when $n=k$ (induction hypothesis)

$$ k^2+ k \mod 2 = 0 $$

then let $n = k+1$

$$ (k+1)^2 + (k+1) \mod 2 = 0 $$
$$ \iff k^2+2k+1+k+1 \mod 2 = 0 $$
$$ \iff k^2+k + 2k + 2 \mod 2 = 0 $$

Based on induction hypothesis $k^2+k \mod 2 = 0$. Which implies we can deduce our statement to

$$ \implies 2k + 2 \mod 2 = 0 $$
Which is true for $\forall k \in \mathbb{N}$ since any $k\in \mathbb{N}$ multiplied by 2 is divisible by 2. Adding 2 to this does not alter the divisibility since 2 is also divisible by 2.

Q.E.D

---

Is my proof correct?

Comment: Yes, it looks fine.

Comment: Yes, this is correct. Another method is just factorising to get $n(n+1)$ and noting that either $n\equiv0\mod{2}$ hence $n(n+1)\equiv0(1)\equiv0\mod{2}$ or $n\equiv1\mod{2}$ hence $n(n+1)\equiv1(0)\equiv0\mod{2}$.

Comment: Duplicate of [Proof by Induction $n^2+n$ is even](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/172435/proof-by-induction-n2n-is-even)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have much knowledge of the mod notation or proofs of this type, but I know this:

notice that $n^2+n=n(n+1)$ which for $n\in \mathbb{N}$ is the same as multiplying two consecutive integers. Since integers alternate between odd and even, we can see that either $n$ or $n+1$ **must** be even, and the other must be odd. since $\text{odd}\times\text{even}=\text{even}$ this shows that $n(n+1)$ must also be even.

I believe this is the equivalent of saying:

$$n \mod 2=0 \,\,\text{or}\,\,(n+1)\mod 2=0$$
$$\therefore n(n+1) \mod 2=0$$

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is correct.

For the base case, you pick $n=0$. I think you assume $\Bbb N=\{0,1,2,\cdots\}$. But many are treat  $\Bbb N$ as $\{1,2,\cdots\}$. Anyway, your result is true for this base case $n=1$ also, since $1+1=2$ which is even.

Alternatively, note that $n^2+n=n(n+1)$, a product of two consecutive terms. So one factor must be even and hence the expression is even!