# Mathematical induction proof; $g_k=3g_{k-1} - 2g_{k-2}$

Tags: recurrence-relations, induction

Can someone help me with this problem? I'm having a hard time proving this.
It's been a long time since I have done mathematical proofs.

> Suppose that $g_1,\ g_2,\ g_3,\ \ldots$ is a sequence of integers defined as follows:
>
> $g_1=3$
> $g_2=5$
> $g_k=3g_{k-1} - 2g_{k-2}$ for all integers $k\geq 3$.
>
> Prove that $g_n=2^n+1$ for every integer $n\geq 1$.

([original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WNsJY.png))

Looking at the problem, it looks like I would want to use induction.

Comment: Use LaTex to format your equation!

Comment: Watch it: the recurrence in the link you gave has a minus where you put a plus...!

Comment: Here are some instructive examples of [proof by induction](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/19485/dominoes-and-induction-or-how-does-induction-work), that help clarify how one *generally approaches* a proof by induction. That may help "clear cobwebs".

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. You may find this [LaTeX tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) helpful.

Answer (score 3):

For $\,k=1,2\,$ it is given , so assume it's true for any $\,k<n\,$ and we shall show for $\,k=n\,$:

$$g_n:=3g_{n-1}-2g_{n-2}\stackrel{\text{Ind. hypothesis}}=3(2^{n-1}+1)-2(2^{n-2}+1)=$$

$$=3\cdot 2^{n-1}-2^{n-1}+3-2=2\cdot 2^{n-1}+1$$

and we're done.

Answer (score 2):

Induction Step:

$\begin{array}{lll}
g_{n+2}& = & 3\cdot g_{n+1}-2\cdot g_n\\ 
        & = & 3\cdot(2^{n+1}+1)-2\cdot(2^n +1)\\ 
        & = & 3\cdot(2\cdot 2^n +1)-2\cdot(2^n+1) \\
        & = & 2\cdot 2^n\cdot(3-1) +(3-2) \\
        & = & 2^{n+2}+1.
\end{array}$

Answer (score 0):

Using [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Solving), $g_k=Aa^k\implies Aa^{k-2}(a^2-3a+2)=0$

For non-trivial solution $Aa\ne 0\implies a^2-3a+2=0\implies a=1,2$

So, $g_k=B2^k+C1^k=B2^k+C$ where $B,C$ are arbitrary constants.

$3=g_1=2B+C$  and $5=4B+C\implies B=C=1\implies g_k=2^k+1$