# Prove by induction $ \sum^n_{i=1}(i-1/2) = n^2/2 $

Tags: algebra-precalculus, induction

This is a question from a test that I wrote and I'm wondering how do you solve it.

Prove by induction that

$$ \sum^n_{i=1}(i-1/2) = \frac{n^2}{2}  $$

*Provide a Base Case, Inductive Hypothesis, and an Inductive Step

Comment: What does "$\sum_{i-1/2}^n$" is ought to mean?

Comment: I apologize, I misquoted it.

Comment: If it is true for $n$, then add $n+1-1/2$ on both sides and do a little algebra on the rhs. Hint: $n^2+2n+1=(n+1)^2$.

Comment: You could look at Arturo Magidin's answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/19485/dominoes-and-induction-or-how-does-induction-work) and see if that helps.  It is excellent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your base case will be the case $n=1$, which says that

$$\sum_{i=1}^1\left(i-\frac12\right)=\frac{1^2}2\tag{1}\;;$$

since both sides of $(1)$ simplify to $\frac12$, the base case is established. Your induction hypothesis will be that

$$\sum_{i=1}^m\left(i-\frac12\right)=\frac{m^2}2$$

for some particular $m\ge 1$, and from it you want to show that

$$\sum_{i=1}^{m+1}\left(i-\frac12\right)=\frac{(m+1)^2}2\;.\tag{2}$$

There’s a pretty standard trick for carrying out this kind of induction step: split the sum on the lefthand side of $(2)$ into the ‘old’ part — the sum from $1$ to $m$ — and the new term, and apply the induction hypothesis to the old part:

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^{m+1}\left(i-\frac12\right)&=(m+1)-\frac12+\sum_{i=1}^m\left(i-\frac12\right)\\\\
&=m-\frac12+\frac{m^2}2&&\text{by the induction hypothesis}\\\\
&=\frac{m^2+2m+1}2\\\\
&=\frac{(m+1)^2}2\;,
\end{align*}$$

which is exactly what we wanted. Since we’ve checked the base case and proved the induction step, we can now conclude that

$$\sum_{i=1}^n\left(i-\frac12\right)=\frac{n^2}2$$

for all integers $n\ge 1$.

Comment: A grader would probably also accept the standard induction proof for $\sum_{i=1}^{n}i =  \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$, followed by the argument $\sum_{i=1}^{n}(i - \frac{1}{2}) = \sum_{i=1}^{n}i - \sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{2}  = \frac{n(n+1)}{2} - \frac{n}{2}  =  \frac{n^2}{2}$

Comment: @RecklessReckoner: *Probably* is probably too strong: I’ve known a fair number of instructors who would not give full credit, arguing that it is not a proof by induction **of the exact result**.

Comment: Fussy! Or if you're responding to the first time my comment appeared, I keep forgetting you can't hit 'Return' in a comment without exiting...

Comment: @RecklessReckoner: (I was responding to the incomplete comment, but I knew what it was supposed to say.) I have mixed feelings. I wouldn’t ask for a specific method of proof in the first place, and I’d accept any legitimate argument. On the other hand, given that the instructor wanted specifically to see whether the student could carry you an induction that he hadn’t seen before, I can see not awarding full marks for a solution that technically doesn’t answer the question. In short, I’d not ask the question, but once it’s asked, I can see requiring that it actually be answered.

Comment: Sorry to ask but could you show the step of: $ \sum_{i=1}^{m+1}\left(i-\frac12\right)=(m+1)-\frac12+\sum_{i=1}^m\left(i-\frac12\right) $

Comment: @user1766555: I just separated the last term of the summation from the first $m$ terms. If $a_i=i-\frac12$, I converted $$\sum_{i=1}^{m+1}a_i=a_1+\ldots+a_m+a_{m+1}$$ to $$a_{m+1}+\sum_{i=1}^ma_i=a_{m+1}+(a_1+\ldots+a_m)\;.$$