# Prove by mathematical induction for all n in set N

Tags: induction

Consider the sequence $\{a_n\}$, where $a_0 = 1$; $a_1 = 2$; $a_2 = 3$ and
$a_n = a_{n-1} + a_{n-2} + a_{n-3}$; $n$ belongs to set $\mathbb{Z}^+$; where $n \ge  3$.

(b) Prove by mathematical induction that for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ , we have that
$a_n \le 3^n$.

Comment: I am a beginner , I don't know how to start

Comment: You might read [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/19485/dominoes-and-induction-or-how-does-induction-work) and see if it gets you started.  Your base case is $a_2 \le 3^2$

Comment: can someone show how to solve it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case all you need from the inductive hypothesis is **(I)** $a_{n-1}\leq 3^{n-1}, a_{n-2}\leq 3^{n-1}$, and $a_{n-3}\leq 3^{n-1}$.  Notice that this is a weaker statement than  $a_{n-i}\leq 3^{n-i}$ for $i\in\{1,2,3\}$, which is still a weaker statement than $a_{k}\leq 3^{k}$ for all $k<n$.  This last statement is the inductive hypothesis if we are using strong induction (or complete induction).

Let's try and prove this with statement **(I)**.  Notice for this inductive hypothesis we need to prove our base case for not just $a_{0}$, but also for $a_{1}$ and $a_{2}$.  This is easy: $a_{0}<a_{1}<a_{2}\leq 3^{2}$.  Now consider the following statement:

**(II)** If $a_{n-1}\leq 3^{n-1}, a_{n-2}\leq 3^{n-1}$  and $a_{n-3}\leq 3^{n-1}$ then $a_{n}\leq 3^{n}$.

If we can prove **(II)** then notice how our base case and **(2)** imply that $a_{3}\leq 3^{3}$.  Additionally, because we have a strictly increasing sequence, this would also imply that $a_{1},a_{2},a_{3}\leq 3^{3}$ so then **(II)** would imply that $a_{4}\leq 3^{4}, a_{5}\leq 3^{5},\ldots,a_{n}\leq3^{n},\ldots$

Proving **(II)** should be a straightforward application of how the sequence $\{a_{n}\}$ is defined.  You could choose to use strong induction as mentioned above, but your base case will still need to be $a_{0}\leq1, a_{1}\leq 3, a_{2}\leq 9$.  Or, as mentioned in an above comment, becase $\{a_{n}\}$ is strictly increasing, it suffices to show that $a_{2}\leq 9$ and we can use weak induction.