# Induction: Sum of the squares of 6 consecutive natural numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, induction

Define for every natural n:

$$ a_{n}=\sum\limits_{i=0}^{5}(n+i)^2$$

in other words, $\ a_n$ is the sum of the squares of 6 consecutive natural numbers, the first number is $n^2$ and the last is $(n+5)^2$.

Prove (by induction) that for every natural $n$ that $a_n$ has remainder $7$ mod $12$.

What I did so far:

$$(n^2+(n+1)^2+(n+2)^2+(n+3)^2+(n+4)^2+(n+5)^2)\mod 12=\\((n+1)^2+(n+2)^2+(n+3)^2+(n+4)^2+(n+5)^2+(n+6)^2)\mod 12$$

I have no idea how to continue, or if it's a good start at all...

Comment: $a_n$ gives a remainder of 7 when divided by 12. That means that $a_n \mod 12 = 7$

Comment: thanks!........I want to add that the OP(me) has no idea about induction, any help appreciated

Comment: You could see Arturo Magidin's answer to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/19485/dominoes-and-induction-or-how-does-induction-work) for an introduction to induction.

Answer (score 5):

Hint:  For induction, you need to prove a base case.  Here it would be to verify that $a_0\equiv 7 \pmod {12}$, which you can do just by computation.  Then assume $a_k\equiv 7 \pmod {12}$ and write $a_{k+1}=\sum\limits_{i=0}^{5}(k+1+i)^2=a_k-k^2+(k+6)^2$  Now if you can show $(k+6)^2-k^2 \equiv 0 \pmod {12}$ you are home.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I'll try that

Comment: any hint how to show that $\ (k+6)^2-k^2 \equiv 0 \pmod{12}$?

Comment: If you expand it out, the $k^2$ terms cancel and each of the other terms has a factor $12$ in it.