# Confusion on unberstanding the proof of induction regarding Fibonacci numbers

Tags: induction, fibonacci-numbers

I am trying to understand the proof that "For all $n\geq 2, F_n^2-F_{n+1}F_{n-1}=(-1)^{n-1}$.Where $F_n$ stands for the Fibonacci number at $n$. I got this proof from a book and here is the proof. 


***F<sub>n+1</sub><sup>2</sup> = F<sub>n+1</sub> (F<sub>n</sub>+F<sub>n-1</sub>) by the definition of F<sub>n+1</sub> 


= F<sub>n+1</sub>F<sub>n</sub>+ F<sub>n-1</sub>F<sub>n+1</sub> +  (F<sub>n</sub><sup>2</sup> - F<sub>n</sub><sup>2</sup>)


=F<sub>n</sub><sup>2</sup> + F<sub>n+1</sub>F<sub>n</sub> - (F<sub>n</sub><sup>2</sup>-F<sub>n-1</sub>F<sub>n+1</sub>)


=F<sub>n</sub>(F<sub>n</sub>+F<sub>n+1</sub>)-(F<sub>n</sub><sup>2</sup>-F<sub>n-1</sub>F<sub>n+1</sub>)


=F<sub>n</sub>F<sub>n+2</sub> - (F<sub>n</sub><sup>2</sup> - F<sub>n-1</sub>F<sub>n+1</sub>) by definition of F<sub>n+2</sub>


F<sub>n</sub>F<sub>n+2</sub> -(-1)<sup>n-1</sup> by the inductive assumption 




Hence F<sub>n+1</sub><sup>2</sup> - F<sub>n</sub>F<sub>n+2</sub> = (-1)<sup>n</sup> and the result follows.***

I understand most of the proof I just don't understand the last part



*F<sub>n</sub>F<sub>n+2</sub> -(-1)<sup>n-1</sup> by the inductive assumption 


Hence F<sub>n+1</sub><sup>2</sup> - F<sub>n</sub>F<sub>n+2</sub> = (-1)<sup>n</sup> and the result follows.*


How does this part prove this thoerom? Arent'nt they just assuming that (F<sub>n</sub><sup>2</sup> - F<sub>n-1</sub>F<sub>n+1</sub>) = (-1)<sup>n</sup> and not proving it?

Comment: Wel, first line is wrong. It should be $F_{n+1}^2=F_{n+1}(F_n+F_{n-1})$.

Comment: We're operating under the inductive hypothesis that $F_n^2 - F_{n+1} F_{n-1} = (-1)^{n-2}$ and trying to show that this implies that $F_{n+1}^2 - F_{n+2} F_n = (-1)^{n-1}$.  Therefore, they assume the former and prove the latter.  As Thomas said, however, the first line of the proof should start with $F_{n+1}^2 = F_{n+1}(F_n + F_{n-1})$.

Comment: OK I just edited the first line

Comment: @ClarkZinzow So is this not the full proof?

Comment: No, it appears that proving that the base case for $n=2$ is missing.

Comment: Please use mathjax to format the question. <sup> etc is hard to read. http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: The last line is rather puzzling. From the previous line, we have $F_{n+1}^2-F_{n+2}F_n=-(F_n^2-F_{n+1}F_{n-1})$. By the induction assumption $F_n^2-F_{n+1}F_{n-1}=(-1)^{n-1}$. It follows that $F_{n+1}^2-F_{n+2}F_n=(-1)^n$.

Comment: I think there is a typo in the "and the result follows" line.  The left subscript should be $n+1$

Comment: I tried to fix that, unfortunately it is not an edit over 6 characters long. :(

Comment: Anyways, this is a version of Cassini's Identity, of which two nice proofs (one of which proves it via inductively proving a matrix identity and taking the determinant of both sides!  Neat!) exist on ProofWiki:  https://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Cassini's_Identity

Comment: @ClarkZinzow:  Got it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume the base cases, $n=1$ and $n=2$ were shown by calculation.  The idea of induction is to show that if it is true for $n$, it is true for $n+1$.  Having shown the base cases, you *assume* it is true for $n$, and *prove* it is true for $n+1$.  The inductive assumption is $F_n^2-F_{n+1}F_{n-1}=(-1)^{n-2}$ and we want to prove $F_{n+1}^2-F_{n+2}F_{n}=(-1)^{n-1}$ so we are allowed to use the former.

One of my favorites on this subject is Arturo Magidin's answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/19485/dominoes-and-induction-or-how-does-induction-work/19488#19488)

Comment: The way I read the proof it was that they just replaced (F_n^2 - F_{n-1}F_{n+1}) with (-1)_{n-1} in lines 5 and 6 of the proof because that was the original assumption. Did I misinterpret what they meant?

Comment: No, you are exactly correct.  That is the assumption that the equation is true for $n$.  We are trying to prove it for $n+1$.  The argument could be better written to state that assumption at the top.

Comment: Wouldn't that cause a sort of circular logic? We assume that (F_n^2 - F_{n-1}F_{n+1}) = (-1)_{n-1} and then we try to use that fact to prove that (F_n^2 - F_{n-1}F_{n+1}) = (-1)_{n-1}.

Comment: No, that is exactly the point of induction.  We assume $(F_n^2 - F_{n-1}F_{n+1}) = (-1)^{n-2}$ and use it to prove $(F_{n+1}^2 - F_{n}F_{n+2}) = (-1)^{n-1}$ where all the indices are increased by one (and your exponents on$-1$ are off by $1$.

Comment: The essence of the inductive hypothesis is that we are assuming that the statement $F_n^2 - F_{n-1} F_{n+1} = (-1)^{n-1}$, call it $P(n)$, is true, and using this fact to show that $P(n+1)$, or $F_{n+1}^2 - F_{(n+1)-1} F_{(n+1)+1} = (-1)^{(n+1)-2}$, is true.  We wish to show that $P(n) \implies P(n+1)$, so we are allowed to assume that $P(n)$ is true while we judge the validity of $P(n+1)$.

Comment: Does that make sense?  I can send you a good number of links about induction, although I am guessing that Ross has a lot more.  I'm rather new here.

Comment: Yes but I still don't understand how to go from the sixth line of the proof to the seventh line of the proof.

Comment: You lost an equal sign on the line that ends "by the inductive assumption".  Once you put that in there is a chain of equalities that justifies your last except that the exponent on $-1$ should be $n-2$.  That makes the exponent on the last line $n-1$ as required for the proof.

Comment: @Ross Millikan OK my confusion more specifically is that they prove through all this algebra that F_{n+1}^2 = F_nF_{n+2} - (-1)^{n-1}. However the book says in the last line of the proof that F_{n+1}^2 - F_nF_{n+2} = (-1)^n. How did they get this line since when you manipulate it algebraically you get F_nF_{n+2}- F_{n+1}^2 = (-1)^{n-1}? So basically how did they make (-1)^{n-1} into (-1)^n and change some of the signs around?

Comment: @RossMillikan also it should be n-1 and be transformed to n. I made a typo at the beginning and its actually  For all n≥2,F^2_n−F_{n+1}F_{n−1}=(−1)^{n−1}. Sorry about that.

Comment: Between the line ending with "by the inductive assumption" and the next line, they changed $-(-1)^{n-1}$ to $+(-1)^n$.  The change of sign reflects the change of one in the exponent.

Comment: @Ross Millikan ok thanks I understand it now!