# The sum of the squares is less than or equal to the square of the sums for all $n$

Tags: inequality

I am trying to understand this proof. Rather an important part of the proof. I have already shown this is true for $n=2$ and am assuming the $a_n$ case is true.

$$(a_1^2 +a_2^2 +\ldots +a_n^2) \le (a_1 +a_2 +\ldots +a_n)^2$$
Want to show that
\begin{align}
(a_1^2 +a_2^2 +\ldots +a_n^2 +a_{n+1}^2) & \le (a_1 +a_2 +\ldots +a_n +a_{n+1})^2 \\
&= (a_1^2 +a_2^2 +\ldots +a_n^2) +a_{n+1}^2 \\
& \le ((a_1 +a_2 +\ldots +a_n) +(a_{n+1}))^2 \\
& = (a_1^2 +a_2^2 +\ldots +a_n^2 + a_{n+1}^2) \\
& \le (a_1 +a_2 +\ldots +a_n)^2 +2(a_1 +a_2 +\ldots +a_n)(a_{n+1}) +(a_{n+1})^2
\end{align}
and here is the part I am not understanding. For some reason the proof moves some of the terms over and I cannot identify what is being replaced or why. My guess is that the terms that moves are the ${n+1}$ terms. But, I am not certain.

$$a_1^2+a_n^2+a_{n+1}^2+\ldots+2(a_1+a_2+\ldots+a_n)(a_{n+1})  \le (a_1+a_2+\ldots+a_n)^2$$

Comment: Your first line does _not_ imply your second. The second line is what you _need_ to show. I think that if you were to write it out carefully you might be able to figure it out on your own.

Comment: please read [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/19485/dominoes-and-induction-or-how-does-induction-work/19488#19488) about induction to see how to structure an inductive proof.  In this case if all the $a_i$ are positive a direct proof is easier.  If you expand the right side you get a bunch of terms that match the left and some more as well.  Subtract the matching ones and you are done.

Comment: Try using binomial expansion on the last term of eq. 3.

Comment: Thank you @Ross and Ethan.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

If you really need to use induction, here's what you need for the inductive step:

Assuming $(a_1^2+a_2^2+...+a_n^2 )  \le (a_1+a_2+...+a_n)^2$

then
$$\begin{align} (a_1+a_2+...+a_n+a_{n+1})^2 &= ((a_1+a_2+...a_n)+(a_{n+1}))^2 \\
&= (a_1+a_2+...+a_n)^2+2(a_1+a_2+...+a_n)a_{n+1} + a_{n+1}^2 \\
&\ge (a_1+a_2+...+a_n)^2 + a_{n+1}^2 \tag{*}\\
&\ge (a_1^2+a_2^2+...+a_n^2 ) + a_{n+1}^2 \\
\end{align}
$$as required. Note that $2(a_1+a_2+...+a_n)a_{n+1}\ge 0)$ for the (*) step.

You do require that all the $a_i$ are not negative.

Being visual myself, I prefer pictures....

[image]

Comment: I always knew this from induction, but this picture is worth 1000 proof steps :)

Answer (score 5):

*inductive step*:

the claim being correct for 
$$(a_1^2+a_2^2+...+a_n^2)  \le (a_1+a_2+...+a_n)^2$$
implies 
$$(a_1^2+a_2^2+...+a_n^2+a_{n+1}^2)  \le (a_1+a_2+...+a_n+a_{n+1})^2$$
**Proof**
\begin{align}
a_1^2+a_2^2+...+a_n^2+a_{n+1}^2 &=(a_1^2+a_2^2+...+a_n^2)+a_{n+1}^2\\
& \leq (a_1+a_2+...+a_n)^2+a_{n+1}^2 \mbox{ (using the assumption)}\\
&=y^2+a_{n+1}^2 \mbox{ (rewriting } y=a_1+a_2+...+a_n)\\
& \leq (y+a_{n+1})^2 \mbox{ (using: } a^2+b^2\leq (a+b)^2)\\
&=(a_1+a_2+...+a_n+a_{n+1})^2 \mbox{ (plug back for } y)
\end{align}

Comment: This proof seems much better than the chosen answer since it does not require assuming that anything is positive. Would you agree?

Comment: @EternusVia - you need to have the $a_i$ positive for the statement to be assuredly true. Consider $2^2+(-2)^2>(2+(-2))^2$.

Comment: @Joffan you are of course right.