# Estimating variance with $\gcd$ in it

Tags: generating-functions, gcd-and-lcm, variance

This is a [continuation from Wilf's exercise on codewords](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2594434/generatingfunctionology-on-codewords) (although this question is (mostly) independent from the previous question).

---

#### Question:

Suppose $n \in \mathbb{N}$ so that it can be written as $n = 2^\alpha n''$,  with $n''$ being odd and consider the formula:

$$\beta_r = \frac{1}{2n} \sum _{j=1} ^{n''} 2^{2^\alpha \gcd(j,n'')} \exp \left(-\frac{2\pi i j}{n''} r\right)$$

> **Wilf's generatingfunctionology** *(Chapter 2, Ex 25e, first part of exercise)*:
>
> Use Parseval's identity and the result of part (d) to find the variance of the occupancy numbers $\beta_0, ..., \beta_{2n - 1}$.

Given $N = \beta_0 + \beta_1 + ... + \beta_{2n - 1} = 2^n$.

<s>Being unfamiliar with this theorem, I have read Parseval's identity from different websites (with different versions?), but am uncertain how this can be used since they seem to have it with infinite sums/integrals, whereas the question is made up of finite sums.</s>

---

**EDIT:**

I figured the first part of the exercise in the answer, which gives variance to be: $$\sigma^2 = \frac{1}{4n^2}\sum _{j=1}^{n'' -1}\left( 2^{2^\alpha \gcd(j, n'') } \right)^2$$

This leaves the 2nd part:

> **Wilf's generatingfunctionology** *(Chapter 2, Ex 25e, second part of exercise)*:
>
> Make an estimate that showsthat the variance is in some sense very small, so that this coloring scheme
> is shown to distribute codewords into color classes very uniformly.

And would like to ask again on how you would make an estimate with a function like $\gcd$ in it?

Comment: Do you have any idea what ”in some sense very small” means here? In other words how good estimate is needed? Like small for large $n$?

Comment: The exercise didn't specify anything specific (eg. for large $n$ or for specific $n$ values), or what this 'sense' is. However, I did find that $\sigma^2 \leq (\beta_0 - \mu)^2$ so that $\sigma \leq |\beta_0 - \mu|$ (using [an inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1180437/the-sum-of-the-squares-is-less-than-or-equal-to-the-square-of-the-sums-for-all-n)), and so I'm guessing perhaps if I could show that $\frac{\beta_0}{\mu} \approx 1$ then that would mean the variance would seem to be small, in that sense I think (not sure how to do that right now).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears I was reading the question wrong, and it wanted to calculate the sample mean & variance, not variance related to discrete random variables.

Since $N= \sum _{r = 0}^{2n-1} \beta_r = 2^n$, we already have $\mu = \frac{2^n}{2n}$.

To calculate sample variance, use the formula:

$$\sigma^2 = \frac{1}{2n} \sum_r {(\beta_r - \mu)^2} = \frac{1}{2n}\left(\sum_r \beta_r^2\right) -\mu^2 \tag{1}$$

To calculate the first term, note that if we let:
$$ \textbf{x} = \left( 2^{2^\alpha \gcd(1,n'')}, 2^{2^\alpha \gcd(2,n'')}, ..., 2^{2^\alpha \gcd(n,n'')} \right)$$

$$f_t = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n''}}\left( e^{2\pi i \frac{t}{n''}}, e^{4\pi i \frac{t}{n''}}, ..., e^{2n''\pi i \frac{t}{n''}} \right)$$

So that:$$\beta_r = \frac{\sqrt{n''}}{2n}\langle \mathbf{x}, f_r \rangle$$

Then $\{ f_0, f_1, ..., f_{n'' - 1} \}$ forms an orthonormal basis in $\mathbb{C}^{n''}$ with the standard inner product. Using [Parseval's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parseval%27s_identity) for Hilbert spaces:

$$\begin{align}\sum_{r=0}^{n'' - 1} \beta_r ^2 &= \sum_{r=0}^{n'' - 1} |\beta_r|^2 \\ &= \frac{n''}{4n^2}\sum_{r=0}^{n'' - 1} |\langle \mathbf{x}, f_r \rangle|^2 = \frac{n''}{4n^2}\langle \mathbf{x}, \mathbf{x} \rangle \\ &= \frac{n''}{4n^2}\sum _{j=1}^{n''}\left( 2^{2^\alpha \gcd(j, n'') } \right)^2 \end{align}$$

And note that from the first term in $(1)$, we use the fact that $cn'' + r \equiv r \mod n''$ given $r = 0, ..., n'' - 1$:
$$\sum_{r=0}^{2^{\alpha + 1}n''-1} \beta_r^2 = \sum_{c=0}^{2^{\alpha +1} -
 1}\sum_{r=0}^{n''-1} \beta_{cn'' + r}^2 = \sum_{c=0}^{2^{\alpha +1} -
 1}\sum_{r=0}^{n''-1} \beta_{r}^2 = 2^{\alpha +1}\sum_{r=0}^{n''-1} \beta_{r}^2$$

Putting these together, we have:
$$\begin{align} \sigma^2 &= \frac{1}{4n^2}\sum _{j=1}^{n''}\left( 2^{2^\alpha \gcd(j, n'') } \right)^2 - \frac{2^{2n}}{4n^2} \\ &= \frac{1}{4n^2}\sum _{j=1}^{n'' -1}\left( 2^{2^\alpha \gcd(j, n'') } \right)^2 \tag{2} \end{align}$$

---

For the second part of the question, [using an inequality for sums of squares](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1180437/246678) and [another inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1129300/246678) yields:

$$\frac{1}{n'' - 1} (\beta_0 - \mu)^2 \leq \sigma^2 \leq (\beta_0 - \mu)^2$$

Note that $\beta_0 / \mu \approx 1$, especially for large $n$:

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\beta_0}{\mu} &= \sum_{j=1}^{n''} 2^{2^\alpha (\gcd(j,n'') - n'')} \\
&= 1 + \sum_{j=1}^{n'' - 1} 2^{2^\alpha (\gcd(j,n'') - n'')} \\
&\leq 1 + \sum_{j=1}^{n'' - 1} 2^{2^\alpha (\frac{n''}{3} - n'')} \tag{3} \\
&= 1 +(n''-1){2^{-2n/3}} \approx 1
\end{align}
$$

In $(3)$, use the fact that $\gcd(j,n'') \neq n''$ if $j = 1,...,n''-1$ and so the next largest value (assuming $n''>1$ and odd) is $\gcd(j,n'') \leq n''/3$. Note the above inequality remains true even if $n'' = 1$.

And in the other direction:

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\beta_0}{\mu} &= 1 + \sum_{j=1}^{n''-1} 2^{2^\alpha (\gcd(j,n'')-n'')} \\
&\geq 1 + \sum_{j=1}^{n'' - 1} 2^{2^\alpha (-n'')} \\
&= 1 +(n''-1){2^{-n}} \approx 1
\end{align}
$$

Also, $\beta_0/\mu \leq 1.5$. So in relative magnitude, $\beta_0 \approx \mu$ as $n$ increases and in this respect, the variance is small in this relative sense (although not in absolute sense).