# Multiplication of two successive Fibonacci numbers

Tags: induction

Recall the Fibonacci function defined by
$f(0) = 0; \\f(1) = 1; \\f(n) = f(n-1) + f(n - 2)$

for all $n \ge 2$
Prove that $f(n) \cdot f(n + 1) = f(1)^2 + f(2)^2 + . . . + f(n)^2.$

Comment: Try using induction on $n$.

Comment: What have you tried?  Yes, induction is the way to go.  Can you do the base case?  [This answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/19485/dominoes-and-induction-or-how-does-induction-work/19488#19488) is a great writeup

Comment: yes i did the base case and after progressing i got this :                               3.[ f(1)^2+f(2)^2+..+f(k)^2+ f(k-1)^2]+2.f(k)^2                                                          which is not the desired formula

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
$$f(n)\cdot f(n+1) = \sum_{k=1}^nf(k)^2$$
$$\implies f(n+1)\cdot f(n+2) = f(n+1)\left[f(n+1) + f(n)\right]$$
$$= f(n+1)^2 + f(n)f(n+1) = \cdots$$