# Induction $n\ge 0, n^2-n$ is even

Tags: induction

I am stuck trying to get the inductive step done on the following proof...

For all $n \ge 0, n^2 - n$ is even.

I have established that the problem is even by setting it equal to $2k$ and then plugging in $n+1$ but after that I am stuck.

Proof: Proceed using induction.
        Base case: Set $n = 0.$ $0^2 - 0 = 0$ which is even.

Inductive step: Set $n\ge0$. Suppose that $n^2-n$ is even. Then there exists integer $k$ such that $n^2-n = 2k$.

Then  $(n+1)^2-(n+1) = 2k$

Comment: I recommend reading [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/19485/dominoes-and-induction-or-how-does-induction-work/19488#19488).  It lays out nicely how to do an induction proof.

Comment: Here is a [MathJax Tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) that'll help you typeset formulas so they become a good bit more readable. I went ahead and did some basic typsetting of your post already. Edit your post to see what I did.

Comment: You're close. Expand your $n+1$ step out. Can you replace any bit of your expression with your assumption? What's left of it? Is the remaining part of it even?

Comment: You could also do the inductive step as moving from $n(n-1)$ to $n(n+1)$ and $n(n+1)-n(n-1)=n(n+1-n+1)=2n$ because you can take out the common factor $n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

\begin{aligned}
(n+1)^2 -(n+1) &= n^2+2n+1-n-1 \\
&= n^2+n \\
&= (n^2-n)+2n \\
&= 2k+2n \\
&= 2(k+n).
\end{aligned}

Answer (score 0):

It's just $n(n-1)$.  One of those terms is even.  Unless you are being forced to induct, then ignore me.

Answer (score 0):

$n \ge 0 $, $n^2 -n$ is even.

$n=0$:  $n^2-n =0$; ok.

Hypothesis:

Assume valid for $n$, I.e $n^2- n $  even.

Step:

Consider: $(n+1)^2- (n+1) = $

$n^2 +2n+1-n-1= $

$(n^2-n) +2n.$

Since by hypothesis $(n^2-n)$ is even,

adding an even number $2n $,

gives an even number.

Hence:

If $n^2-n$ is even then

$ (n+1)^2 -(n+1) $ is even.