# Prove that $\frac{k^7}{7}+\frac{k^5}{5}+\frac{2k^3}{3}-\frac{k}{105}$ is an integer.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-writing, induction

Prove that $$\frac{k^7}{7}+\frac{k^5}{5}+\frac{2k^3}{3}-\frac{k}{105}$$ is an integer using mathematical induction.

I tried using mathematical induction but using binomial formula also it becomes little bit complicated.

Please show me your proof.

Sorry if this question was already asked. Actually i did not found it. In that case only sharing the link will be enough.

Comment: Put all terms on common denominator and prime factor the denominator and if possible numerator.

Comment: It is $15k^7+21k^5+70k^3-k$

Comment: You now need everything to be divisible by $105 = 3\cdot 5\cdot 7$

Comment: Sorry ! I did not get what you want to point out. If you are saying about proving divisibility it is still a task : how to prove it by induction ? The p:k+1 will contain nearly 20 terms

Comment: Read [this marvelous answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/19485/dominoes-and-induction-or-how-does-induction-work/19488#19488) on how to make an induction proof work

Comment: Maybe induction makes it easier. If it is included in the question then you should add it to the question.

Comment: @ross thank u so much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@I like Serena has a great answer but since the OP asked for a proof by induction, I'll show what that would look like. Define
$$f(k)=\frac{k^7}{7}+\frac{k^5}{5}+\frac{2k^3}{3}-\frac{k}{105}=\frac{15k^7 + 21k^5+70k^3-k}{105}$$

For our base case, let $k=1$. Then we have
$$f(1)=\frac{15+21+70-1}{105}=1$$
which is an integer. Now suppose $f(k)$ is an integer for some $k\geq 1$. We want to prove that $f(k+1)$ is also an integer. To that end, observe that
\begin{align}
f(k+1)&=\frac{15(k+1)^7 + 21(k+1)^5+70(k+1)^3-(k+1)}{105}\\
&=\frac{15k^7 + 105k^6+336k^5+630k^4 + 805k^3+735k^2+419k+105}{105}
\end{align}
Therefore 
\begin{align}
f(k+1)-f(k)&=\frac{105k^6+315k^5+630k^4+735k^3+735k^2+420k+105}{105}\\
&=\frac{105(k^6+3k^5+6k^4+7k^3+7k^2+4k+1)}{105}\\
&= k^6+3k^5+6k^4+7k^3+7k^2+4k+1
\end{align}
Which is an integer, say $N$. Rearranging this gives $f(k+1)=f(k)+N$ and since $f(k)$ is assumed to be an integer from the induction hypothesis, $f(k+1)$ is the sum of two integers, hence an integer.

Comment: Thanks 4 your effort

Answer (score 10):

We have:
$$\frac{k^7}{7}+\frac{k^5}{5}+\frac{2k^3}{3}-\frac{k}{105}
=\frac{15k^7+21k^5+70k^3-k}{3\cdot 5\cdot 7}
$$
To prove this is an integer we need that:
$$15k^7+21k^5+70k^3-k\equiv 0 \pmod{3\cdot 5\cdot 7}$$
According to the *Chinese Remainder Theorem*, this is the case iff
$$\begin{cases}15k^7+21k^5+70k^3-k\equiv 0 \pmod{3} \\
15k^7+21k^5+70k^3-k\equiv 0 \pmod{5}\\
15k^7+21k^5+70k^3-k\equiv 0 \pmod{7}\end{cases} \iff
\begin{cases}k^3-k\equiv 0 \pmod{3} \\
k^5-k\equiv 0 \pmod{5}\\
k^7-k\equiv 0 \pmod{7}\end{cases}$$
*Fermat's Little Theorem* says that $k^p\equiv k \pmod{p}$ for any prime $p$ and integer $k$.

Therefore the original expression is an integer.

Comment: Nice. You are a fast writer!

Comment: Excellent answer!

Comment: Fermat's Little Theorem says that if $p$ is prime and $k$ is an integer, then we have $k^p=k$ (mod $p$). How does it follow from $k^p=k$ (mod $p$) that $k$ is an integer?

Comment: It doesn't @EuxhenH. I just stated the result first and the conditions afterwards. It's exactly how you say it is.

Comment: @EuxhenH an integer raised to an integer is always an integer because integers are closed under multiplication and addition.

Comment: I actually forgot that $k$ is an integer. My bad. (Although that needs to be specified in the statement) Thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 2):

Call the expression $f(k)$. As it's a degree $7$ polynomial, it obeys the recurrence
$$\sum_{j=0}^8(-1)^j\binom8jf(k-j)=0.$$
Thus
$$f(k)=8f(k-1)-28f(k-2)+56f(k-3)-70f(k-4)+56f(k-5)-28f(k-6)+8f(k-7)-f(k-8)$$
so that if $f$ takes eight consecutive integer values, by induction, all subsequent
values are integers too.

Comment: Very interesting. What causes the recurrence equation?

Comment: @mathreadler iterated differences.

Comment: Does it work only with 7 degree ? Please give a reference where i can find this relations !

Comment: @MDesmond $\Delta f(k) := f(k+1)-f(k)\, $ reduces the degree of the polynomial $\,f(k)\,$  since leading terms cancel. So if $f$ has degree $n$ then $\,\Delta^{n+1} f(k) = 0\,$ yields a recurrence for $f(k).\,$ Above is the binomial expansion using $\,\Delta = S-1\,$ where $\,S\,f(k) = f(k+1)\,$ is the shift operator. See any textbook that treats recurrences or finite differences.

Answer (score 2):

hint...if you only want to use induction, let $$f(k)=15k^7+21k^5+70k^3-k$$
and consider $$f(k+1)-f(k)=$$

For the induction step you have to show this is divisible by $105$

So, for example, $$(k+1)^7-k^7=7N+1$$ where $N$ is an integer, etc...

Can you finish?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [binomial transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_transform) to prove that

$$\frac{k^7}{7}+\frac{k^5}{5}+\frac{2k^3}{3}-\frac{k}{105}
\\={k\choose1}+28{k\choose2}+292{k\choose3}+1248{k\choose4}+2424{k\choose5}+2160{k\choose6}+720{k\choose7}$$

Answer (score 1):

Base case for $k=1$: $$\frac{1^7}{7}+\frac{1^5}{5}+\frac{2*1^3}{3}-\frac{1}{105}=1$$

Now, assume for some k that $\frac{k^7}{7}+\frac{k^5}{5}+\frac{2k^3}{3}-\frac{k}{105}$ is indeed in integer.

Then $$\frac{(k+1)^7}{7}+\frac{(k+1)^5}{5}+\frac{2(k+1)^3}{3}-\frac{k+1}{105}=\\\frac{\sum_{i=0}^7\binom{7}{i}k^i}{7}+\frac{\sum_{i=0}^5\binom{5}{i}k^i}{5}+2\frac{\sum_{i=0}^3\binom{3}{i}k^i}{3}-\frac{k+1}{105}=$$

Extracting the highest indexed term from each sum (and the $-\frac{k}{105}$ at the end):  $$\frac{k^7}{7}+\frac{k^5}{5}+\frac{2k^3}{3}-\frac{k}{105}+\frac{\sum_{i=0}^6\binom{7}{i}k^i}{7}+\frac{\sum_{i=0}^4\binom{5}{i}k^i}{5}+2\frac{\sum_{i=0}^2\binom{3}{i}k^i}{3}-\frac{1}{105}$$

By the induction hypothesis, the sum of the first four terms is an integer so, if we can show the rest of the above sum is an integer, we will be done. Use the fact that, for any prime, $p$, $p|\binom{p}{k}$ where $1\leq k\leq p-1$. This is because $$\binom{p}{k}=\frac{p(p-1)...(p-k+1)}{k(k-1)...1}$$

$p$ divides the numerator but not the denominator (as $1\leq k\leq p-1$) so $p|\binom{p}{k}$

So each term in the remaining sum with index $i$ $\geq1$ and $\leq p-1$ ($p$ being the respective prime in each sum) is divisible by the corresponding $p$ in the denominator and produces an integer. The only non-integer terms left will be the ones at $i=0$, i.e.  $$\frac{\binom{7}{0}k^0}{7}+\frac{\binom{5}{0}k^0}{5}+\frac{2\binom{3}{0}k^0}{3}-\frac{1}{105}=\frac{1}{7}+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{2}{3}-\frac{1}{105}=1$$

So $\frac{(k+1)^7}{7}+\frac{(k+1)^5}{5}+\frac{2(k+1)^3}{3}-\frac{k+1}{105}$ is a sum of integers making it an integer.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $ $ Note that $\ 3\!\cdot\!5\!\cdot\!7\mid \overbrace{3\!\cdot\! 5\, (\color{#c00}{k^7\!-\!k})+ 3\!\cdot\! 7\, (\color{#c00}{k^5\!-\!k})- 5\!\cdot\! 7 (\color{#c00}{k^3\!-\!k})+ 3\!\cdot\! 5\cdot\! 7\, k^3}^{\Large{\rm sum\ = \ this/(3\cdot 5\cdot 7)}}\, $ by $\,\rm\overbrace{little\ \color{#c00}{Fermat}}^{\Large p\ \mid\ \color{#c00}{k^p-k}}$

**Remark** $ $ More generally this shows that if $\,p,q,r\,$ are primes and $\,a,b,c,k\,$ are integers

$$\quad\ pqr\,\mid\, aqr\,(k^p\!-\!k)+bpr\,(k^q\!-\!k)+cpq\,(k^r\!-\!k)$$

Comment: Note that we don't actually have to recognize the above form to prove it is $\equiv 0\pmod{p}\,$ for $\,p = 3,5,7,\,$ since simply computing it $\!\bmod p\,$ using $\,k^p\equiv k\,$ easily proves it is $\equiv 0,\ $ But I showed the form of the expression to reveal how it was constructed.

Answer (score 0):

Because
 $$\frac{k^7}{7}+\frac{k^5}{5}+\frac{2k^3}{3}-\frac{k}{105}=\frac{k^7-k}{7}+\frac{k^5-k}{5}+\frac{2(k^3-k)}{3}+k.$$

Comment: Same as my answer after dividing by $\,3\cdot 5\cdot 7\ $

Comment: They are similar but my equality we can see immediately. See please better that I wrote.

Comment: In my experience most students don't "immediately" see such fraction expansions.. Rather they first put it over a common denominator, as I did. From that it is easy to read off the fraction expansion (but there is no need to rewrite the key (Fernat) divisibilities in fraction form).

Comment: I think you see that $-\frac{1}{105}=-\frac{1}{7}-\frac{1}{5}-\frac{2}{3}+1$. If so, we are done! I think, it's much more better than your writing.

Comment: How do you propose that one "sees" things like that *in general*?

Comment: It's another problem already. But for the given problem my way it's the best way. I think.

Comment: You still haven't explained your claim that we  "can immediately see" the fraction expansion, and how it is any different from the integral version I gave earlier.

Comment: @Bill Dubuque I really don't understand you. I wrote the solution with less steps than you. The reasoning is the same, of course. Actually, I did not see your solution before than I wrote mine.

Comment: What is a "step". Maybe if you explain your "steps" then we can understand how you  "immediately see" it.