# How to prove by method of induction a statement with factorials

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, proof-explanation

The question:

Prove that for all positive integers $n \geq 4$, $2^{n} < n!$

The base case is fine, but how do you proceed with inductive step?

$(2^{k} < k!) \implies ( 2^{k+1} < (k+1)!)$

Comment: For a good look at induction proofs, see [this great answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/19485/dominoes-and-induction-or-how-does-induction-work/19488#19488)

Comment: You've written the inductive step oddly. To keep the logic straight in your head, it might help to write correctly: $$(2^{k} < k!) \implies ( 2^{k+1} < (k+1)!)$$ or, in words, $$2^{k} < k! \,\,\text{implies}\,\, 2^{k+1} < (k+1)!$$

Comment: Yes you're right. Sloppy on my end. Will change.

Answer (score 0):

Intuitively, to go from $n!$ to $(n+1)!$ you multiply by $n+1$, which is greater than $2$.