# Prove the statement true for every positive integer k

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Prove that $\frac {k^7}{7} + \frac {k^5}{5} +  \frac {2k^3}{3} - \frac {k}{105}$ is an integer for every positive integer $k$.

I have tried to do it with induction, but I am unable to do so
.

Comment: Aside: I think this is a well-crafted question. It calls a bit to the Chinese Remainder Theorem, Fermat's Little Theorem, perhaps to some p-adic arithmetic, but in a slightly elementary and different way.

Comment: I recommend [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/19485/dominoes-and-induction-or-how-does-induction-work/19488#19488) as an excellent introduction to induction.  If nothing else, you can just try all the residues $\bmod 105$ in a spreadsheet and note that it is true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By Fermat's little theorem, for any positive integer $k$, $70k^3\equiv k^3\equiv k \pmod 3,$ $21k^5\equiv k^5 \equiv k \pmod 5$, and $15k^7\equiv k^7 \equiv k \pmod 7$.  Therefore $3, 5, $ and $7$ all divide $15k^7+21k^5+70k^3-k.$  Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $f(k+1) - f(k) = {k}^{6}+3\,{k}^{5}+6\,{k}^{4}+7\,{k}^{3}+7\,{k}^{2}+4\,k+1$