# How can I prove this by well ordering principle?

Tags: proof-writing, induction, well-orders

So the problem is that:
 Use the Well Ordering Principle (WOP) to prove that

> $2+4+···+2n = n(n+1)$

for all $n > 0$.

1.My first thought is that we can create a set named $C::=\{n>0\mid2+4+···+2n ≠ n(n+1)\}$. This set is not empty and all its elements are non-negative integers. So according to the well ordering principle we can conclude that this set has a minimum number called $k$.

2.So we have $\color{red}{2+4+···+2k ≠ k(k+1)}$ (marked as a). While $k/2$ is smaller than $k$, we can also conclude that $2+4+···+2(k/2) = (k/2)(k/2+1)$. Therefore,we can conclude that $\color{red}{2+4+···+2(k/2)+2k = (k/2)(k/2+1) + 2k}$ (marked as b).

3.Now the problem should change to prove the right side of the expression b equals to the right side of the expression a,that is to say, we should prove that $k(k+1)=(k/2)(k/2+1) + 2k$, so here the conflict happen and we can say that the presume is false.Therefore,the original proposition should be true.

The problem is :How should I prove that $k(k+1)=(k/2)(k/2+1) + 2k$? It seems that I can never prove this.So maybe I thought wrongly at first.But how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Don't use $\frac k2$ (what if $k$ is odd?).  Use $k-1$.  As $k-1 < k$ we know $2 + 4+ ... 2(k-1) = (k-1)k$.  Then just add $2k$ to both sides and .....

Comment: Whenever I see a question on induction I recommend [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/19485/dominoes-and-induction-or-how-does-induction-work/19488#19488)

Comment: @fleablood wow,I know it now,thanks

Comment: By the way.  I doubt you need the well ordering principal.  Induction would work just fine.

Comment: @fleablood Sure.But the problem requires that I should only use the wop to solve it

Comment: Well, induction and this sort of well-ordering go hand in hand.  If you can prove the "induction step" that $P(k-1) \implies P(k)$. Then $P(1)$ the induction principal says all $P(n)$ while the w.o.p says there is not first term where $\lnot P(n)$.

Comment: Ah.... The question was not $2 + 4 + ..... + 2^k = k(k+1)$ (which it doesn't) but $2 + 4 + .... + 2k$.  It'd have been clearer if the had added the last or previous term.  $2 + 4 +6 + .... + 2(k-1) + 2k$.  The is the old "does $4$ mean $2+2$ or $2\times 2$ ambiguity".

Comment: You can use the well ordering principales with things other than $k\to k-1$.  A famous example is proving every $n=\sum_{k=0}^m a_i 2^k; a_i\in \{0,1\}$ for some set of $\{a_i\}$ and some $m$.  Proof: Let $N$ be the first number that does not.  Let $2^m \le N < 2^{m+1}$ then $N-2^m < 2^m$ *does*. And as $N = (N-2^m)+2^m$, then $N$ does.  Contradiction.  That uses $k\to k-2^m$.  It's conceivable I could make up a case with $k \to \frac k2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you will demonstrate in this exercise is that there is a very natural equivalence between well-ordering and induction.

You did a good job by defining $C$.  But, in fact, $C$ is empty, which is what you need to prove.  So, by means of contradiction, you need to assume that it is not.  Then, as you suggest, it has a minimal member $k$.  Now, you have to split into two cases: either $k=1$ or $k-1$ is a positive integer that is not in $C$  The first case would be the base case of an induction proof, and the second is essentially the induction hypothesis that will lead to a contradiction when you conclude that $k\notin C$ by doing the algebra.