# Ordinary induction - Number of nodes in a full binary tree

Tags: graph-theory

Question: Use ordinary induction to show the minimum number of nodes for a full binary tree of height h.

I started to play with it and I believe I got the answer $2^{h+1}-1$.
However, I am not able to write the proof by induction.

And another small question, I believe that in this case the minimal and maximal amount of nodes are similar (since it's a full binary tree). Am I wrong?

Thanls

Comment: You could review [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/19485/dominoes-and-induction-or-how-does-induction-work/19488#19488) for how to think of an induction proof.  Yes, the number of nodes is fixed.

Comment: You add _some_ leaves when you obtain tree of height $h+1$ form tree of height $h$. How many? That's the induction step.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the use of 'minimum' here seems odd since a full tree has precisely $2^{h+1}-1$ nodes as you say.

The inductive step would be as follows.

Assume a tree of height $k$ has $2^{k+1}-1$ nodes. Then a tree of height $k+1$ has $(2^{k+1}-1) + 2^{k+1}$ nodes. This equals $2^{k+2}-1$ nodes as required.