# Inductive proof showing a tiling of trominoes on a $2i \times 3j$ board with no squares missing.

Tags: proof-writing, induction, tiling

**Question:**

How to use mathematical induction to show how to tile a $2i \times 3j$ board with $L$ trominoes. The board must be tiled with no squares missing.

**Where I am at:**
[image: Link to my working]

**What I don't understand:**

How to write the inductive hypothesis and inductive step. I started by defining the base case, then tried to use the principle of divisibility to show any multiple of $2$ or $3$ can be divided by $2$ or $3$ respectfully.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I always suggest [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/19485/dominoes-and-induction-or-how-does-induction-work/19488#19488) when people ask about induction.

Comment: @RossMillikan I suspect the question is less about understanding how induction works, and more about how to format a formal induction proof when the core of the argument is in pictures.

Comment: @user744868:  the writeup was not there when I posted that, but I think it is still a good way to help people think about things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say induction is the wrong tool for this proof.  You have sketched a nice constructive proof, showing you can tile a $2 \times 3$ rectangle and you can chop a $2i \times 3j$ rectangle into $2 \times 3$ rectangles.  Presumably you have been asked to use induction, so here we go.

Note that you have two variables, $i$ and $j$, so you will need two inductions.  I will do $j$ first.  The base case is that you can tile a $2 \times 3$ rectangle, which you have shown.  Then we assume you can tile a $2 \times 3k$ rectangle and show you can tile a $2 \times 3(k+1)$ rectangle.  A $2 \times 3(k+1)$ rectangle can be cut into a $2 \times 3k$ rectangle and a $2 \times 3$ rectangle.  The first can be tiled by the inductive assumption and the second can be tiled as we have shown.  This shows that for all $j$ we can tile a $2 \times 3j$ rectangle.

That result is the base case for the $i$ induction.  Now we assume we can tile a $2k \times 3j$ rectangle and want to show we can tile a $2(k+1) \times 3j$ rectangle.  Again, we can split the $2(k+1) \times 3j$ rectangle into a $2k \times 3j$ and a $2 \times 3j$ rectangle.  The first can be tiled by the inductive assumption and the second can be tiled by the base case.  Hence for all $i$ we can tile a $2i \times 3j$ rectangle.