# Show that for every positive integer $n$, $2^n$ is deficient

Tags: proof-writing, solution-verification, proof-explanation, alternative-proof

I am trying to complete an induction proof on this problem, but cannot figure out the final steps. I understand the logic behind what makes this theorem true, and will explain it here before I dive into what I have written so far for the proof.

For example, take $2^4$. To check if this is a deficient number, we look at the sum of it's divisors, which are $2^0 + 2^1 + 2^2 + 2^3$.

$2^4 = 16$ and $2^0 + 2^1 + 2^2 + 2^3 = 15$. Since $16 > 15$, we can say that $2^4$ is a deficient number.

This can be generalized to $2^n > \sum_{i = 0}^{n-1} 2^{i}$

For my proof so far, this is what I have:

**Proof (by induction)**: Let $n$ be any positive integer, where we need to show $2^n$ is deficient. Also let the sum of the divisors of $2^n$ equal $2^0 + 2^1 + ... + 2^{n-1}$. We can say that $2^n$ is deficient if it is greater than the sum of it's divisors. For the base case, let $n = 1$. Then, $2^n = 2$, and the sum of the divisors is equal to $2^0$. Since $2^1 > 2^0$, the theorem holds true for this case.

Next, we want to find if the theorem holds for $n + 1$. Therefore: ... **This is where I need help**

I want to try and use $2^{n+1} > \sum_{i = 0}^{n} 2^{i}$ in some way, but don't know how as it has been a while since I've worked on proofs. Any help or alternative ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you know the formula for the sum of a geometric progression, then you can avoid induction.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca How might I go across doing this?

Comment: I recommend [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/19485/dominoes-and-induction-or-how-does-induction-work/19488#19488) whenever someone wants to structure an induction proof.  You structure the sum for $n+1$ as the sum for $n$ plus whatever is new.  Use your assumption for the sum for $n$

Comment: Might be easier and be less likely to trip on your feet if you prove the *stronger* statement $\sum_{d|2^n} d = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} 2^k = 2^n -1$.  Then $\sum_{d|2^{n+1}} = \sum_{k=1}^n 2^k = (\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} 2^k) + 2^n= (2^n-1)+2^n = 2^{n+1} -1$.... Although you *can* simply say $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} 2^k \ne 2^n$ so $\sum_{k=0}^n 2^k \ne 2^n + 2^n = 2^{n+1}$. But you are likely to trip on your feet if you do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $$2^n\gt \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} 2^i$$ and so we have $$2^n\ge 1 + \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} 2^i$$ because both sides are integers, and so $$2^{n+1}\ge 2 + \sum_{i=1}^{n} 2^i $$
$$= 1 + \sum_{i=0}^{n} 2^i $$
$$\gt \sum_{i=0}^{n} 2^i$$.

Comment: A few questions about this. What properties allow you to include $... \ge 1 + ...$? From my understanding, you are using $2^0$, and then when $n+1$ comes in, it becomes $2^1 = 2$. My next question is about the ending of the proof. Are you simply saying $2^{n+1} > \sum_{i=0}^{n} 2^i$?

Comment: If $x,y\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $x\gt y$ we have $x\ge y+1$ and also $2x\gt 2y+1$.

Comment: So $2^n$ is $x$, and $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} 2^i$ is $y$ in this scenario?

Comment: A proof by induction assumes the proposition is true for $n$ and then uses some algebra to prove that the proposition is then true for $n+1$. As is it also true for the base case, it is now true for all $n$. I have assumed the result is true for $n$, and then using this, show that is would then be true for $n+1$ as well.

Comment: @Pecker; yes, and we know $x$ is strictly greater than $y$, and so we can also say without doubt that $x$ is greater than or equal to $y+1$ as they are both integers..

Answer (score 0):

$1 + 2 + ...... + 2^{n-1} \ne 2^n$ so

$1 + 2 + ..... + 2^{n-1} + 2^n \ne 2^n + 2^n =2\cdot 2^n =2^{n+1}$

Comment: Could you elaborate on how this proves deficiency with $2^n$?

Comment: Huh?   That was your induction hypotheses.  If $2^n$ was deficient this proves the deficiency of $2^{n+1}$.  If you want to prove $2^n$ is deficient then your induction hypothesis is that $2^{n-1}$ is deficient.  If $1 + 2 + ..... + 2^{n-2} \ne 2^{n-1}$ then $1+ 2+ .... + 2^{n-2} + 2^{n-1} \ne 2^{n-1} + 2^{n-1} = 2^n$.

Comment: I see now. I thought you were saying something different with the $\ne$ sign. Thank you!